# AJAX não atualiza div pelo id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, onde preciso retornar a mensagem de validação para o usuário em uma div na própria página de login, entretanto a mensagem de erro está aparecendo na página de validação.Estou usando Bootstrap e PHP com PDO.

#### Login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />



        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
<body>

<form id="loginform"  role="form" action="validaLogin.php" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
               <label for="login" class="control-label">Login</label>

               <input type="text" 

               class="form-control" 
               id="inputLogin" 
               name="login" 
               placeholder="Insira seu login" 
               title="Insira seu Login" 
               required>

               <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>



          </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
               <label for="inputSenha" class="control-label">Senha</label>

               <input type="password" 

               class="form-control" 
               id="inputSenha" 
               name="senha" 
               placeholder="Insira sua senha" 
               title="Insira sua Senha" 
               required>

               <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               <div class="help-block with-errors" id="login-alert"><span id="mensagem"></span></div>
    </div> 



    <div class="form-group margin-top-pq">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
              Entrar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div> 


</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="check.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### check.js:

O código abaixo deveria retornar uma mensagem de erro na div #mensagem

```js
<script >$('document').ready(function(){

  $("#btn-login").click(function(){
    var data = $("#loginform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url  : 'Login.php',
      data : data,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function()
      { 
        $("#btn-login").html('Validando ...');
      },
      success :  function(response){            
        if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
          $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
          $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none')
          window.location.href = "selectPersonagem.php";
        }
        else if(response.codigo == "0"){     
          $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
          $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block');
          $("#mensagem").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
        }
        }
    });
  });

});
```

---

#### validaLogin.php

Nesta página eu faço a validação server side, bloqueando o ID após 5 tentativas de erro, tudo funciona, mas ao invés de mostrar a mensagem de erro na página login, a mensagem de erro aparece na própria *valida.php* desta forma:

```
{codigo":"0","mensagem":"Usu\u00e1rio n\u00e3o autorizado, voc\u00ea tem mais 4 tentativa(s) antes do bloqueio!"}
```

Ou seja ele retorna o JSON, mas no check.js não acessa a informação dele.

Este é um dos  trechos do código que deveria retornar a mensagem:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Constante com a quantidade de tentativas aceitas
define('TENTATIVAS_ACEITAS', 5); 

// Constante com a quantidade minutos para bloqueio
define('MINUTOS_BLOQUEIO', 30); 

// Require da classe de conexão
require 'conn.php';


// Dica 1 - Verifica se a origem da requisição é do mesmo domínio da aplicação
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://localhost/loginphp/login.php"):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => 'Origem da requisição não autorizada!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;
```

Estou iniciando em ajax e PHP, retirei esse código deste tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/sistema-de-login-com-ajax-e-php)

Comment: Como você está realizando o login? Você envia o POST para **Login.php**, mas lá não tem o código para validação do login.

Comment: Acontece que você está verificando se o valor do `código` é igual a 1, porém você não retorna o valor `1` no arquivo *validaLogin.php*, você está retornando apenas o `0`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr este é apenas parte do código da página, ele funciona corretamente e retorna o JSON com a resposta, o problema está na hora de pegar a informação no JSON e mostrar na id.

Comment: Entendi. Mas ele está retornando o JSON com o código `1` também? No seu caso, o JavaScript não vai funcionar pois o usuário será redirecionado ao clicar no botão entrar, para evitar isso adicione `type="button"` no botão e corrija a URL em `$.ajax({ ... })`

Comment: Sim, está retornando com 1 também.

Comment: No caso quando coloco como Button no type, ele muda o texto do botão, mas não envia para a página de validação

Comment: quando você coloca "1" o conteúdo se torna string e não inteiro, já tentou retirar as aspas? ou tente parseInt(response.codigo)